# How to make a bevel on text

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, text-object, geometry

How can I make a bevel, like in the "Gibson," for my personal inscription?
Is there an automatic method to do so?

[image: text and reference image]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134971/round-beveled-text

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64980/how-to-make-a-metal-emboss

Answer (score 11):

You can use curve bevel it is not an automatic one-click-solve-all solution, it *will* lead to artifacts in narrower zones and cause artifacts in pointy tips.

[image: Curve Bevel]

In fonts or curves with width variations it will never yield a perfectly triangular bevel like the Gibson logo.

You can tweak it locally, but that will always require manual adjustment and modeling.

[image: Bevel Adjust]

For these types of complex shapes you best bet is really converting to mesh with a **proper topology** and manually modeling it. Triangulated mesh from raw curve to mesh conversion will not do.

[image: Manual beveling]

Comment: I want to know how the center line appears. In the below image as u have show u have converted to mesh and then deleted faces and then connected the faces. And what u did not get and how the center line came and u pull in z axis I have posted the question and i have same problem i want to raise from the center can u plz clear me .http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70242/how-to-bevel-correct-way?noredirect=1#comment122070_70242

Comment: @atek Press `Ctrl` +`R` to loop cut

Comment: thanks for replying but as the link mention to my mesh i cannot create mesh http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70242/how-to-bevel-correct-way?noredirect=1#comment122070_70242