# How to bevel correct way

Tags: bevel

[image]

I have made the svg file and imported and then converted to curve.
As i have make with the red is my original mesh and the below is unmark bevel mesh.

I want my mesh to be bevel from the center and it should not created space or gap as seen the below mesh. The mesh should make bevel from the center mark in green.

Im i doing correct way or is there any other way or how should i make the bevel without creating gap or space in middle of mesh.

As the mesh is present same shape should be bevel from the center.

[image]

**result**

[image]

**Reference image**

[image]

Comment: The green curve is not strictly "in the middle" of your figure, so I can't see how an algorithm could figure out where to place it. Probably for this task it's easier to build two curves and create faces between them (if your goal is to get flat bevel).

Comment: Thanks for replying i have added the reference image that effect i want on my mesh

Comment: Related question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58457/how-to-make-a-bevel-on-text

Comment: @Carlo Thanks for replying I want to know how the center line appears. In the below image as u show he has converted to mesh and then deleted faces and then connected the faces. And what he did not get and how the center line came and he pull in z axis. i have same problem i want to raise from the center can u plz clear me

Comment: @atek I didn't 'convert to mesh' it was purposefully modeled by hand to do so easily. If you notice it has a quad-based topology with 4 sided faces only, so it can be easily loop cut.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos can u give me the best solution for my mesh how can it work a best bevel maybe similar as u shown in the .gif of text

Comment: Start from one of the ends of your shape, and trace over twice by hand , once for each side of the curve. Draw two lines with a **mesh object** with **the same amount of edges** for each side, so that they can later be bridged together, and have a quads only topology. Then you can loop cut and place an edge at the middle.

Comment: I will try and a request if i get a reference .gif how it works will be thankful

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure that when you are using bevels you don't want any ngons  on your model. These are faces that contain more than four vertices.

In this situation sense you are trying to only bevel the center of the model try using the inset tool.

This can be accomplished by the "I" key while you have the desired faces selected.

Here is a link for how to use the inset tool from the Blender documentation.

https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/inset.html

Comment: Thanks for replying with the option i have got a fair result. I have attach the result and i have a reference image (gold) that effect i need on my mesh.

Comment: Oh if you are trying to generate text in blender there are two way you can go about it. You can either use the create text tool which gives you a bunch of different tools to work with including a bevel tool for the text.  Or you can create a plane then extrude that plan into the desired shape. Then inset the plane to get the beveled look.

Comment: above mr carlo given the link Thanks for replying I want to know how the center line appears. In the below image as u show he has converted to mesh and then deleted faces and then connected the faces. And what he did not get and how the center line came and he pull in z axis. i have same problem i want to raise from the center can u plz clear me http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58457/how-to-make-a-bevel-on-text

Answer (score -2):

If I can be honest, I don't know in short. Though it was something that seems very practical and it really frustrated me I couldn't figure it out, there must be an add-on somewhere for it,

Though I think I may have come up with an alternative solution. If I can make some assumptions, it is important that you manipulate a curve not a mesh....You are not using it for a path and only for geometry... and you will be converting to a mesh at some point...

If this is the case, this file may have a solution that is not correct but may work, I have split the curve into two separate curves with two 'vector' aligned 'handle' at the points of overlap. Also manually added a curve to create the position required for a bevel.

So now all you have to do, is convert both curves to a mesh (You can join the curves if you prefer), Join the two objects together with Ctrl + J and then remove doubles, and now you will have a line of polygons at the exact point you want a bevel, just select them and raise appropriately.

https://www.mediafire.com/folder/hhdz4v4fnhbwh/Assisted_Files

(make sure you keep the vector aligned handles exactly overlapped, keep the resolutions exactly the same and do not edit the 'bevel curve' without altering both, I would delete the internal curve on one of the objects if you want to edit it's position, re-seperate it and then attach it exactly to the other curve object or add hooks/handles to edit both curves simultaneously (would you like me to do this for you?))

I hope this worked for what you intend to achieve, unfortunately unless I know the exact reason you want this feature I cannot give you a more suitable way to achieve it, this was just my best solution so far. I do want to investigate more, this does seem to useful.﻿
Show less

Comment: can u clear it little bit more with images or .gif