# Why curve bevel not in shape

Tags: bezier-curves

I have a curve profile and circle curve. I want to bevel or spin around the circle to make that profile shape but im getting different result

**This is my profile and curve**[image]

This the result im getting with that profile which is different

[image]

May i know how can i fix and where im going wrong.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bevel placement uses the object origin as center, check your bevel object local origin and place it accordingly where desired, like at one of the ends, for example.

Both your curves need severe cleanup, and require several steps to achieve good bevel.

First you need to set the center of the bevel object correctly using the 3D cursor. Enter edit mode on the bevel object, select the desired vertex for center, then use the snap menu <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > Cursor to Selected*

Exit edit mode and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> > *Center to Cursor*

Your bevel will come out inverted, so you will need to scale the bevel object by a factor of -1 in the X axis

It will also seem out of scale because the circle is not uniformly scaled. Apply the scale to the circle with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > Apply > Scale*, then enter edit mode, select all vertex and in the properties shelf use the *Radius* property to set the radius of all vertex to 1.0

You may also need to invert the bevel object curve direction in edit mode using the *Switch Direction* button under the tool shelf.

[image: Curve]

Comment: not getting exactly can u plz make a .gif and help me out the blend file attached

Comment: I can but I will only be able to do it later tonight, not currently at the computer

Comment: If anyone else beats me to it, or wants to post an answer or edit mine in the meant time feel free to do so

Comment: i have ask a question yesterday and i got link from the answer and u have created the center line to bevel from it plz may i know in detail how is created http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58457/how-to-make-a-bevel-on-text

Comment: Press `Ctrl` +`R` to loop cut. Answer updated above

Comment: Thanks for the .gif after bevel object by a factor of -1 in the X axis then as mention apply scale to circle. going the edit mode and selecting the circle the next step i did not get whats did u press the pop came set curve radius

Comment: Thanks i found and got it smooth shape. May i know what wrong i did to make so long process to get that shape. Normal bevel we just make the shape and bevel

Comment: You did nothing wrong *per-se*, Blender bevel workflow is a bit unpredictable and can take a bit of guessing to get right