# Curve bevel is acting in the wrong dimension-Why?

Tags: bezier-curves

I had expected the profile to go around the quadrant, but it is flattened in a weird way, Why is this happening? thank you.

P.S. applying the scale did not solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/curve-bevel-function-scale https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70394/why-curve-bevel-not-in-shape

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot I guess you want to achieve a result like this:

[image: expectation]

Now I assume, your curve object has a scale of 1 and a rotation of 0° on all axis. Then a profile object (also scale 1 and rotation 0°) is oriented on this curve in the following way:

- The origin of your profile object will be placed on the starting point of the curve. If you don't want your profile to be offset, its first vertex must be at the origin.
- Looking at the curve's direction from start to end, the "left side" of the curve should be the positive X direction of your profile.
- Then the upward direction of the curve will be the positive Y direction of the profile (so if you want it to go downwards, it's the negative Y direction).

[image: curve locations]

Which means, if you want your profile to bulge "outwards" (which is to the "left" in this case) of your curve and "downwards" from the original curve, your profile should be placed extending to the +X and -Y direction in the following way:

[image: profile orientation]

Of course, as mentioned before, this is valid for objects with applied or reset scale and applied or reset rotation. Scaling, rotating etc. may have an effect on this, also if vertices on the original curve are tilted which might not be visible if it's an endpoint.

Comment: Thank you all. @Gordon Brinkmann Many thanks for the detailed explanation. As I understand, the origin of the curve doesn't play a role, and the final shape only relies on the origin of the profile, did I get it right?

Comment: @Meriil I think you've got it right. And you're correct, the origin of the curve doesn't matter. Although people often say the origin of the curve, its starting point and the origin and starting point of the profile should be in the same location, this is simply not true. The profile will be placed relative to it's origin on the starting point of the curve, the profile's +X and +Y dimension will be left and up of the curve (Z dimension doesn't matter). The profile will be offset from the curve as far as it is offset from the profile's origin.