# Creating Volcano/Funnel Shape Around SVG Contour in Blender

Tags: extrude, text-object

I'm currently attempting to create a volcano or funnel shape around the contour of an SVG, incorporating either a logo or text.

My goal is to extrude all the contours in such a way that it resembles a regular extrusion of thin letters at the top but gradually thickens towards the bottom, akin to a volcano shape. Specifically, I'm aiming for the extruded wall shape to be diagonal, extending outward.

I've experimented with various tools and software, but I haven't been able to achieve the desired effect.

Does anyone have experience or insights into **whether Blender can accomplish this task effectively?

Similar to this but with all letters combined:

[image: Extruded text with diagonal wall]

It's for 3D print a mold to pour resin on it:
[image: 3D printed mold]

[image: 3D printed mold]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71137/how-to-extrude-x-and-y-axis-on-a-traced-object-flatten/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70394/why-curve-bevel-not-in-shape/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92632/creating-an-bevel-inset-on-an-imported-svg/92635#92635

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extrude with the addon called *Mesh: Edit Mesh Tools*, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Offset Edges > Extrude*, then move down the extrusion, but it will need some rework in some cases, especially if you want to 3D print:

[image]

I'm not sure there's any easy way to do it as in your case the faces will intersect, maybe use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Offset Edges > Offset* instead of *Extrude*, in the *Operator Box* decrease the *Width*:

[image]

Then you'll need to clean the topology yourself, example with a single letter:

[image]

Then bridge between the 2 meshes:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! I've installed the addon, but I'm encountering difficulties with the font geometry. It seems to be broken as I consistently receive the error message "overlap detected: select non-overlap edge loops" whenever I attempt to execute the extrusion.

Comment: Maybe share your file with at least one of your letters?

Comment: Here you have my source files. https://www.mediafire.com/folder/zh2elrun0bj54/Blender 

I get the error "Overlap detected. Select non-overlap edge loops" when I try to Extrude with CtrlE > Offset Edges > Extrude

Comment: In your case I'm not sure that there's any other way but to clean the topology yourself, I've edited my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I'll start investigating now how to clean the topology! 