# How to show the panel with Geometry - Modification - Offset / Extrude

Tags: geometry, panel

In this question:

[How to make a bevel on text](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58457/how-to-make-a-bevel-on-text)

... the screenshot:

[image: Curve Bevel]

... shows Geometry panel, with Modification: section, with Offset and Extrude inside - how can I show this panel?

Comment: It isn't the panel, those are options of the selected object in the Properties editor. They will be shown for any object of the curves type. If you [edit] your question with some context may be it could be easier to answer it.

Comment: Those options are part of the properties for **Text** objects. **Curve** objects will have a similar menu, but not meshes.

Answer (score 1):

ah found it, partially through here:

https://spolearninglab.com/curriculum/software/3d_modeling/blender/blender_02.html

[image: copy from link]

You simply have to click on that icon with two white dots connected with a curved line (have no idea how its called, when I do a mouseover over it, I get:

```
Type of active data to display and edit
Data: Object data
Python: SpaceProperties.context
bpy.Data.screens("Default") ... context
```

... which tells me absolutely nothing - but by the icon image, I'd guess this submenu is called "Curves"); and then you get Geometry panel...

Comment: The tab is called 'object data'. It is the same name the tab would have for meshes, where there is a triangle instead of a curve