# How to get this type of relief?

Tags: extrude, bevel, svg

i made this "3d" effect in photoshop, but i want to make it real 3d in Blender, how can i do that? i'm working with a SVG so i can import it in Blender, thanks!

[image]

[image]

update >> using bevel and offset

[image]

Comment: Which version of Blender are you using?

Comment: SVG paths will be imported as curves in blender. Then look at this post on how to use curve bevel: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58457/how-to-make-a-bevel-on-text

Comment: @IsraelBamidele i'm using 2.79b

Comment: @cegaton thanks! i have tried that way, but it don't work to get the look i need because the bevel increase object size and the offset generate mesh errors

Comment: Please update your question, explain what you have done, what you have tried that has not worked, so that we don't waste each other time or suggest things that you have tried already.

Comment: you could do it manually, you draw the silhouette with vertices, then fill the whole thing with quads, and at last catch and drag the central edge loops?

Comment: @cegaton you are right, i have added an image.

Comment: @moonboots thanks for ur suggestion! actually i use blender only for specific needs, like this one, so i don't know too much about Blender, i hoped that there was a easy way to get that effect, it didn't look complicated at first

Comment: There is no magic button to do what you want on a single operation. If you bevel, you need to go to the parts where the image is getting distorted and manually edit the radius for the control point of the curve, like in the link posted above.

Comment: it won't be complicated to make it manually, it will take several minutes, but yes it's not an easy automatic way

Comment: ok, thanks for your help guys. Bevel is approximated but don't look like i want, so i will try to make it manually, i suppose that it will need some sculpting, right?

Answer (score 4):

I would do it manually:

- Put your picture as a background image.
- Create a plane, begin to follow the shape of the object with some extrusions.
- When you have finished, create some edge loops on the centre of each quads line, where the bump is supposed to happen.
- drag the edge loops to create the bump.
- Give your object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, and click the *Smooth Shading* button to smooth it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! i'm following your advice :D