# Unable to bevel an object from illustrator

Tags: bevel, svg

I am playing with some object drawn in illustrator. Converted it to an object in blender, extruded and now I want to give it all over smooth edges, to turn it into a smooth 3d object, but have some troubles.
Bevel modifier doesnt seem to work, no matter what i set. It is quite complex, how to work it out?

Here's what i did:

1. Imported an SVG object into Blender.
2. Converted it to an object from curves.
3. Added some extrusion
4. Cleaned it using mesh clean up
   [image]

second pic is what im trying to achieve, 3d object from photoshop, where I used a very simple inflate tool.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/142071/how-to-get-this-type-of-relief/142084#142084

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58457/how-to-make-a-bevel-on-text

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134971/round-beveled-text