# How do I fix this simple intersecting geometry?

Tags: modifiers, geometry

I have this shape here I made from curves:
[image]

It works fine in renders and viewport but I want to use it as object for boolean but it's not working because it has intersecting geometry:
[image]

How do I fix the intersecting geometry to make it usable for boolean?

Comment: you mean manually, or procedurally?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58457/how-to-make-a-bevel-on-text/58498#58498

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could:

- Delete 'Faces only' the curve-shape, leaving a network of edges
- [Knife Project](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/knife_project.html) the network down onto a plane

[image]

- Delete away unwanted parts of the plane
- <kbd>X</kbd> > Limited Dissolve unwanted edges (there may be some minor repair work to do)
- Extrude the result, which is then OK for a Boolean.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is realy useful. Fixing this all manualy would have been a nightmare since I have a lot of different shapes like this.