# Chiseled text - how to go from 2d quads to raised center

Tags: modeling, topology, bevel, text-object

**UPDATED:** linked a new .blend with references packed. My apologies!

I'm very new to modeling, and I need to try to recreate a particular V (a client's logo, the Photoshop fake 3d chisel look), getting as close a match as I can.

[image]

I've googled many tuts on doing chiseled text in Blender. Two examples:

[a popular one from here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58457/how-to-make-a-bevel-on-text)

[and one on manually topologizing text](https://blenderartists.org/t/quad-mesh-fill-svg-to-mesh-curve-to-mesh-objects/645606)

I have roughed out the 2d topology for the V, but I don't know if I've thought it out correctly (the top caps probably won't deform right), but Blender can simple subdiv, so the edge flow seems to kinda work?

[image: screen capture of 2d topology of serif area of letter V]

Two questions:

1 - There are reference images in the attached Blender file. Have I got the basic shapes down for this to deform the way the reference image appears to?

2 - If I use this method, how would I go about raising the center? I've done a hard-chisel version by raising the center line on a simpler topology (below), but it's not quads, and I don't know how to umm...puff out the sides to get the rounded look of the reference.

[image: hard chisel V in blender overlaid with reference image]

I've tried proportional move, but either it's too complex a shape, or I don't understand the options well enough...the vertices are not equidistant, so I get odd bulges at the irregular areas. Part of it is my rough modeling, but...

Any help on either aspect of the question is appreciated.

Comment: the blend file does not contain the reference images.

Comment: It would be simpler to embed a reference image in your post? And/or: Image Editor > Header > Image > Pack the ref. image into your .blend

Comment: I've updated the blend file to one with references embedded - I didn't realize they were just linked.

Answer (score 1):

You could create this topology that flows around the peak:

[image]

Move the edge loops:

[image]

Add some edge loops, move the edge loops to round the sides or sharpen the edges:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is a much smarter topology! Well explained, and answers everything...thank you! Should I accept now, or is it considered good form to give others a chance to answer and gain rep?

Comment: You can wait a bit  ;)