Convex top of Letters (as shown in picture)
I cannot figure this one out.  I want the top of the letters to have a slight convex shape to them.  Bevel creates too sharp of a profile.  I'm a beginner at Blender but this doesn't seem like it should be out of my skillset.


Can you add an image of what you have so far in Blender? - Window > save Screenshot menu then edit your question and add your image.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72662/trying-to-make-glossy-volume-shapes/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/315370/chiseled-text-how-to-go-from-2d-quads-to-raised-center https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134971/round-beveled-text https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58457/how-to-make-a-bevel-on-text https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64980/how-to-make-a-metal-emboss

Hello and welcome. This question seems to have been asked before in multiple forms over time, and already has various answers but you never acknowledged any of them. We are not sure if you aware of the existing posts but none of the described techniques address your particular requisites, or you simply didn't do any research at all. Could you [edit] you post and clarify how your question differs from the suggested duplicates? Otherwise could you rephrase it to focus on a particular step you are stuck with?
